# Connecting to an asmx webservice with WCF through a proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, proxy, asmx

**Sorry answer found while typing**

I am trying to connect to an external webservice that requires username/password authentication through a proxy. I am using Visual Studio Express 2008 to generate a service reference

- I have connected to the same
  webservice using a web reference.We
  only had to set a larger timeout
  because it takes a long time to
  finish.
- I have connected to another
  webservice that does not require
  username/password authentication
  with a generated service reference
  and some settings to get it through
  the proxy.

So my thought would be to
    take this reference, point it to the
    correct webservice and add
    authentication.

The config I am using without security:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <system.net>
        <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
          <proxy bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://***.***.****:80" />
        </defaultProxy>
      </system.net>
        <system.serviceModel>
          <bindings>
            <customBinding>
              <binding name="AreaWebServiceSoap12">
                <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </textMessageEncoding>            
                <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" />            
              </binding>
            </customBinding>
          </bindings>
          <client>
            <endpoint address="http://www.****.*****.****.com/samplewebservice/service.asmx"
                    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="AreaWebServiceSoap12"
                    contract="ServiceReference1.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap" />
            </client>
        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

I have added te following code to my call for authentication:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  ServiceSoapClient s = new ServiceSoapClient();
  s.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = @"username";
  s.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = @"password";

  Service.RawGpsData[] result = s.GetRawGpsData(0);
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("done:{0}",result.Length));
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Just using this setup gives an error as expected:

*The HTTP request is not authorized with client authentication scheme Anonymous. The authentication header from the server is received, is NTLM.*

Now I get lost and start trying silly things because I am just starting to use WCF.

When I add the following section to the config

```
 <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"></security>
```

I get the following error:

*The binding CustomBinding.http: / / tempuri.org / for the contract AreaWebServiceSoap.AreaWebServices is configured with a verification mode for which a transport level with integrity and confidentiality is required. The transport can not provide integrity and confidentiality.*

Sorry, while typing this question I stumbled upon the answer myself. I still think people might be interested in this and all comments and thoughts are still welcome. So I will leave the question here and make it community and post the answer myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the binding to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<customBinding>
            <binding name="AreaWebServiceSoap12" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
                <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                  messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              </textMessageEncoding>              
              <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"  
                  maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Ntlm"
                  bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                  keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                  realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                  useDefaultWebProxy="true" />              
            </binding>
          </customBinding>
```

So set authenticationScheme="Ntlm"

Answer (score 1):

And here is how you can connect without proxy:

http://blog.bodurov.com/Create-a-WCF-client-for-asmx-web-service-without-using-web-proxy