# WCF client with proxy settings set to "Use automatic configuration script"

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I'm currently developing an application that needs to communicate with a webservice on the internet. Internet explorer is until know the only application that is connecting to the internet through a proxy server.

The proxy settings are setup to "Use automatic configuration script".

I have kept the default setting

```
<binding useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
```

And additionally set

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Basic"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

But no luck. I keep getting "(407) Proxy Authentication Required."

I have done some Google-ing, but the solutions do not seem to fit my situation.

Short update:
The application should run with the default user credentials, and use those credentials 
through NTLM to authenticate with the proxy. But even when I set the client to do that it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Are you sure you need to send credentials to proxy via Basic authentication? That would require you to set user name and password in client credentials of the proxy.

Comment: Good point. Changing it to Windows right now. But I assume it means it automatically will use default credentials.

Comment: Does this answer help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289601/connecting-to-an-asmx-webservice-with-wcf-through-a-proxy

Comment: did you try setting proxy.useDefaultCredentials  to true programatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep the `<binding useDefaultWebProxy="true" />` setting, and make sure [`useDefaultCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) is set to true in your app.config file (this setting is `false` by default):

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
</system.net>
```

For more information, see my blog post "[Using HTTP Proxy Servers](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/01/using_http_proxy_servers.html)".

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you any background on why but setting:

```
<binding useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
```

Works for me in my current environment when getting your exact error.
Everyting in Windows seems to use the IE-configurable internet settings which include the default proxy. Internet explorer fixes this up for you neatly when running but if you try to retrieve the service wsdl or so using Firefox I´m guessing you would end up having a user login prompt.

In any case, try to false the default proxy.

Comment: When reading the WCF documentation, setting it to false would use the setting on user level. But this I tried it before, and it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Ok, that explains why it works for me however. Too bad it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that kerberos authentication does not work very well across different firewalls. Many organizations have setup up their proxy to use AD for authentication and will only allow the proxy to access internet sites. This setup does not work well for web services and I suspect this is your problem.